# XCode(8.3.3) using Xcode managed profile for exporting app ipa

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, ipa, code-signing-certificate

While my setting for "automatically manage signing" was unchecked
[image]

When i try to export the archive (Save for Development Deployment), XCode was using  XCode managed profile for exporting the app.
[image]

Anyone know why XCode using XCode managed provisioning profile instead of the provisioning profile setting set in my Build Options?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

When you manually set Provisioning profile while archive then you have to manually select provisioning profile while generating .ipa too. I am talking in Xcode 9.2, please update your Xcode.

Comment: Since my company app only need to deploy for iOS 10, so i use XCode 8.3.3, is there any way to solve this in my current XCode version?

Comment: You can set deployement target in though you update Xcode